# JavaScript - контекстное меню

Tags: jquery, javascript

Нужна помощь. Все никак не могу разобраться как реализовать такую штукенцию на javascript и еще с jquery в придачу.

Вообщем нужно сделать контекстное меню, которое при нажатии на ссылку выдвигает его с помощью функции show(), то есть делает видимым меню, при повторном сворачивает (это я-то сделал). Вот еще нужно, чтобы при щелчке на весь остальной сайт, кроме этого контекстного меню и ссылки, должно сворачивать это меню. Пробовал события mouseover и mouseout - не помогли. Вообщем вот функция:

```
var Box = {

    Profile: function (id_menu) {
        var my_menu = document.getElementById(id_menu);
        if (my_menu.style.display == "none" || my_menu.style.display == "") {
            $('#' + id_menu).slideDown(300);
        } else {
            $('#' + id_menu).slideUp(300);
        }
    }
```

Comment: в javascript есть событие oncontextmenu. Почему бы не использовать его.

Answer (score 1):

В jQuery есть такая замечательная функция как `toggle`, в ней перечисляете функции которые должный выполняться при клике на ссылку, допустим что jQuery мы уже подключили:

Например: у нас есть ссылка с `id`:

```
<a href="" id="href"></a>

<ul id="menu">
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu 2</li<>
</ul> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(ducument).ready(function(){
    $('#href').toggle(function(){
        $('#menu').show();
    },function(){
        $('#menu').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ toggle отменили.

**Note:** *This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.*

в данном случае как раз подойдет 

    $('#href').click(function(){$('#menu').toggle()})

Answer (score 0):

Часто для таких вещей (закрытие по клику вне зоны) делают прозрачный див на все доступное пространство, а дальше играются с z-index, чтобы меню было поверх него, весь остальной сайт под ним, и клик по этому диву ведет к закрытию меню. Очевидно, что открытие меню этот див показывает, а закрытие - скрывает.